# How to change property/Attribute from JSON string in c#?

Tags: c#, json.net

I am having JSON string like

```
{"name":"studentname","Lastname":"lastnameofstudent"}
```

I want to change the name property/key to FirstName not the value of this property. using Newtonsoft JSON lib.

Example:

```
string json = @"{
  'name': 'SUSHIL'
}";
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
var abc = obj["name"];
obj["name"] = "FirstName";
string result = obj.ToString();
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by "I have key in json string". Nor is it clear whether you're trying to change the *name* of the property or the *value*. A [mcve] would make it much easier to help you.

Comment: I want to change property name not it's value.

Comment: So please update your question with that information, along with a complete example showing what you've tried...

Comment: @PieroAlberto: That question is about a situation where the code is using a serialized class. I don't see any indication of that here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is probably just to assign a new property value, then call `Remove` for the old one:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string json = "{ 'name': 'SUSHIL' }";
        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
        obj["FirstName"] = obj["name"];
        obj.Remove("name");
        Console.WriteLine(obj);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "FirstName": "SUSHIL"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon got final solution. I am doing mistake like obj["name"] = "FirstName"; assignment.